# $http GET not showing in display in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an app in AngularJS, where I am grabbing the data from the backend to display on the view. But, for some reason, I am getting the data in my console but not in my view. I will be so thankful if any one can help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

> Here is my code. -Services

```
    app.factory('user', ['$http', function($http) {
    var userInfo = { 
        getUserInfo: function () {
            return $http.get('https://************/*****/**/***********')
        }
    };
    return userInfo;
}]);
```

> home page(view)

```
    <div class="users" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userSearch" >



    <a href="#/users/{{ user.id }}">
    <img ng-src="{{user.img}}"/>
    <span class="name">{{user.first}} </span>
    <span class="name">{{user.last}} </span>

   <p class="title">{{user.title}} </p>
  <span class="date">{{user.date}} </span>


</a>
```

> HomeController

```
    var isConfirmed = false;
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, user, $http) {
    if (!isConfirmed) {
        user.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userInfo = response.data;
            isConfirmed = $scope.userInfo;
            console.log($scope.userInfo);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
});
```

> App.js

```
    var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute']);


    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.inactive = true;

        $scope.confirmedAction = function() {

        isConfirmed.splice($scope.person.id, 1);

        location.href = '#/users';

    }

});
```

> index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Portal">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>







    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />



  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
          <h3>Portal</h3>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
          <div ng-view>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/UserController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
      <script src="js/services/users.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunk for this so that we can understand what you are trying to accomplish ? I don't see anywhere in your html where a controller was defined. We'd need to see all the different pieces so a plunk will help.

Comment: @lacoder check updated question

Comment: @lacoder you got what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

change your `ng-repeat="user in users"` to `ng-repeat="user in userInfo"`
as your assigning and consoling only `$scope.userInfo` in your controller

Comment: So, I have change it to 'userInfo', but I get an "Error: [filter:notarray]" type error in console.

Comment: So, I have  change it to 'userInfo', but I get an "Error: [filter:notarray]" type error in console.

Comment: thats related to the filter your using in the repeat...check with removing that first....if your getting data then cross check your filter

Comment: I removed that in the console, it gets my data shown, but nothing still does not show in the view.

Comment: can you  provide your consoled data so that we can work around

Comment: never post data like this if u want a quick help,how we can fetch data from img??

Comment: no i took a screen shot from my console, so you can see what is shown in my console. I am not fetching data from img.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144457/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-suzy-hakobyan).

Answer (score 1):

The property you assign data has to be same as of binded to view.

As per your HTML data should be in `users`. So do it like : `$scope.users = response.data;`.

or if you assign data to `userInfo`, then bind it on html. like :

```
 <div class="users" ng-repeat="user in userInfo | filter:userSearch" >
```

Comment: so, in my home controller I have it as  '$scope.userInfo = response.data;' so instead of that use this '$scope.users = response.data;.' , right?

Comment: if yes, I am getting a undefined.

Comment: do you get data from server, in `response.data` ?

Comment: just print `{{users}}` on screen , and see if it really filled up or not ?, because it is very straight forward mechanism

Comment: no, I am not getting anything when I print out {{ users }} in my home.html.

Comment: do you really fetch data ?, because your get call is in if condition., and since no data printed on screen , that means data is not assigned to `users`